# Copy dll into subfolder in output directory when using NuGet

Tags: msbuild, nuget-package, output-directory

Let's say I have some NuGet package that contains c++ dll and interop for this dll. When I install this package, I see that my scproj file gets updated with the following reference:

```
    <Reference Include="Interop.MyCppAssembly, Version=1.1.1.1, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
         <HintPath>..\..\packages\MyNuGetPackage.1.1.1.1\lib\Interop.MyCppAssembly.dll</HintPath>
         <Private>False</Private>
         <EmbedInteropTypes>False</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </Reference>
```

You can see that HintPath points to the folder where my packages are installed. You can also see that I set **Copy Local** to false so Interop.MyCppAssembly.dll won't be copied to my output directory (let's call it **bin**) during the build. I did it intentionally, because I don't want to put any third party dlls into my **bin** folder to avoid mess in my output directory. Instead, I would like to create a subfolder in my **bin** 
like **bin\ThirdPartyLibs** and put all third party dlls there.

But how can I do this? I know I can set CopyLocal to true, and then use Post Build Event to move Interop.MyCppAssembly.dll from **bin** to **bin\ThirdPartyLibs** but I don't like this. Is there any other solution how to copy dll to the **subfolder** of the output directory during the build?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I'm currently working on the same issue.